# How do I get this function to run when a button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, function

I made a function that will show you a random quote whenever you press a button, the problem is that the function runs when the page is loaded. All the code works as it should but I can't find the reason why it runs immediately. I think the problem is that I call the function outside the function itself at `var result = generateQuote(quotesArray);`, but when I place it in the function itself it breaks.

I hope someone can help me find the problem, here is the code:

JavaScript:

```
const quotes = new Object();

const quotesArray = [{
    quote: "“Be yourself, everyone else is already taken.”",
    author: "- Oscar Wilde",
} , {
    quote: "“Two things are infinite: the universe and human stupidity; and I'm not sure about the universe.”",
    author: "― Albert Einstein",
} , {
    quote: "“The important thing is not to stop questioning. Curiosity has its own reason for existing.”",
    author: "― Albert Einstein"
} , {
    quote: "“Expect everything, I always say, and the unexpected never happens.”",
    author: "― Norton Juster"
} , {
    quote: "“What lies behind you and what lies in front of you, pales in comparison to what lies inside of you.”",
    author: "― Ralph Waldo Emerson"
} , {
    quote: "“We are part of this universe; we are in this universe, but perhaps more important than both of those facts, is that the universe is in us.”",
    author: "―Neil deGrasse Tyson"
}]

    const button = document.querySelector('.generateQuote');
    const author = document.querySelector('#quoteAuthor');
    const quoteText = document.querySelector('#quote');

button.addEventListener('click', generateQuote);

function generateQuote(array) {
    var quoteIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotesArray.length); 
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { 
            var randomQuote = array[quoteIndex]; 
          } 
          return randomQuote; 
        }
        var result = generateQuote(quotesArray); 

        quoteText.innerHTML = result.quote;
        author.innerHTML = result.author;
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Quote Generator</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">

</head>
<body>
    <div class="border">
    <div class="quoteContainer">
        <h2 class="title">Quote Generator</h2>
        <button class="generateQuote">Generate a inspiring quote</button>
        <blockquote id="quote"><h2>quote</h2></blockquote>
        <h3 id="quoteAuthor">Author of the quote</h3>
    </div></div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you have 2 problems here. One is the below code is being run right on load:

```
var result = generateQuote(quotesArray); 

    quoteText.innerHTML = result.quote;
    author.innerHTML = result.author;
```

This is causing the render of the quote on page load. You should instead wrap it in a function to prevent that. For instance you can write something like this:

```
function generateQuote(array) {
    var quoteIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotesArray.length);
    var randomQuote;

    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { 
        randomQuote = array[quoteIndex]; 
    }

    return randomQuote;
}

function renderQuote() {
    var result = generateQuote(quotesArray); 

    quoteText.innerHTML = result.quote;
    author.innerHTML = result.author; 
}
```

Then on button click, you can bind the renderQuote:

```
button.addEventListener('click', renderQuote);
```

Comment: Thank for the fast reply, i tried the code but it says the the code after i close the ```for``` statement is unreachable.

Comment: Yes, sorry about that! Just changed the code - this should work fine now

Comment: Yes it works perfectly fine! thank you so much. i couldnt find out why it didnt worked but now i understand. :)

Answer (score 1):

You also need to pass the `quotesArray` as a parameter to the function

So replace

```
button.addEventListener('click', generateQuote);
```

with

```
button.addEventListener('click', () => generateQuote(quotesArray));
```

Answer (score 0):

create a function and insert everything.
and create button with onclick option.

```html
<input type="button"  onclick="generateQuote()>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your call around a function block and pass appropriate parameters

```
  button.addEventListener('click', function (){generateQuote(quotesArray)});
```

Answer (score 0):

On the second parameter you want to call a fonction reference, not the function itself. So you can do the following:

```
 button.addEventListener('click', function(quotesArray){
   var quoteIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotesArray.length); 
   for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { 
        var randomQuote = array[quoteIndex]; 
      } 
      return randomQuote; 
    }
    var result = generateQuote(quotesArray); 

    quoteText.innerHTML = result.quote;
    author.innerHTML = result.author;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just remove the line `button.addEventListener('click', generateQuote);`

And in your HTML code add the onClick attribute as shown below

```
<button class="generateQuote"  onclick="generateQuote()">Generate a inspiring quote</button>
```

Since you use `button` you dont need to add a listener on top of that, only if you used `<input type="button"` you had to add the listener.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to use [let instead of var](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var).
2. I don't get why you're running a for loop in the function, it seems unnecessary.
3. I shortened the code a bit.
4. You don't need an EventListener with a button, only when using an input of type button. Add this to your button's properties instead: `onclick="generateQuote()"`

Let me know if it works!

```
function generateQuote(array) {
    let quoteIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotesArray.length); 
    let randomQuote = array[quoteIndex]; 

    quoteText.innerHTML = randomQuote.quote;
    author.innerHTML = randomQuote.author; 
}
```

Comment: That's not the right syntax to use `addEventListener` , you must pass a function and not a value.

Comment: You're right, I thought both were possible. I updated the answer, thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

I see that you already have your question answered. If you don't mind, I'd like to suggest a way to clean up your code.

Put this at the top inside of the head tag in your HTML document:

```
<script src="https://randojs.com/1.0.0.js"></script>
```

And then you can replace your entire generateQuote(array) function with this:

```
function generateQuote(array) {
    return rando(array).value;
}
```

I hope this makes things simple for you. Cheers.